# Cannot load page on Firefox when testing localhost with Nightwatch and Selenium

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js, geckodriver

I am building a suite of automated integration tests using [Nightwatch](http://nightwatchjs.org/), a Node wrapper for the Selenium WebDriver API. I was able to get it working correctly for Chrome, but not for Firefox (or Safari, for that matter).

I think the problem have to do with GeckoDriver vs. Firefox Driver. I have configured Nightwatch to use GeckoDriver in my `nightwatch.json`. But Selenium appears to be looking for Firefox Driver, based on the terminal output of `nightwatch -e firefox --verbose`. See below:

```
INFO Request: POST /wd/hub/session/2c156cf4-10cb-44b2-8b1f-c12312b4633f/url 
 - data:  {"url":"localhost:9000"} 
 - headers:  {"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Content-Length":24}
ERROR Response 500 POST /wd/hub/session/2c156cf4-10cb-44b2-8b1f-c12312b4633f/url (1218ms) { state: 'unknown error',
  sessionId: '2c156cf4-10cb-44b2-8b1f-c12312b4633f',
  hCode: 1111219279,
  value: 
   { additionalInformation: '\nDriver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver\nCapabilities ...
```

Here is my Nightwatch config file:

```
{
  "src_folders": ["./nightwatch/tests"],
  "output_folder": "./nightwatch/reports",
  "custom_commands_path": "",
  "custom_assertions_path": "",
  "page_objects_path": "./nightwatch/tests/pages",
  "globals_path": "",

  "selenium": {
    "start_process": true,
    "server_path": "./nightwatch/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar",
    "log_path": false,
    "cli_args": {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver": "./nightwatch/drivers/chromedriver",
      "webdriver.gecko.driver": "./nightwatch/drivers/geckodriver"
    }
  },

  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    },

    "chrome": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome"
      }
    },

    "firefox": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "marionette": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And for good measure, here is the `nightwatch/pages/index.js` file I am trying to access in my tests:

```
module.exports = {
  url: 'localhost:9000',
  elements: {
    // stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it worth, for the moment we decided to stick with the current ESR version of Firefox, which works with Selenium out-of-the-box.

We did some tries with this new version of Firefox and the new driver, but it was not stable enough to continue.

My advice would be to install the ESR version of Firefox, see if you can make it work this way. If it does, then move to the next step (ie, test against the latest version).